# Trouble with unit tests in vs2013 c++ project

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to create unit tests for my c++ code in vs2013, which contains CLocalDBManager.h and CLocalDBManager.cpp files, determining single class, and includes 4 .h files with structures and sqlite sources.
I tried to do everything like [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1085171/How-To-Do-Unit-Testing-with-Cplusplus-in-Visual-St), and it worked fine for copypasted code, but when I try to use my own code, something goes wrong.

When I create new unit test project and add HelloWorld.cpp and HelloWorld.h files from the link above, everything works flawlessly, but when I  try to add CLocalDBManager.h and CLocalDBManager.cpp in new one, compiler goes crazy - it founds a lot of errors in .cpp file, like here:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJnEc.png)

All includes and other stuff made exactly as in example, and I really don't know what to do with it.

There is code from CLocalDBManager.h file:

```
#include "SLandlord.h"
#include "SOffice.h"
#include "SMapSegment.h"
#include "SBuilding.h"
#include "sqlite3.h"
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

#pragma once

class CLocalDBManager
{
public:
    template <class T> int LoadItemByID(int nID, T *sResult); //exception
    std::vector <int> FindBuildingsInArea(int nTopCoordinate, int nBottomCoordinate, int LeftCoordinate, int RightCoordinate);

    static int _LoadMapSegmentByIDCallback(void *vResult, int nNumberOfColumns, char **cData, char **cColumnNames) _NOEXCEPT;
    static int _LoadBuildingByIDCallback(void *vResult, int nNumberOfColumns, char **cData, char **cColumnNames) _NOEXCEPT;
    static int _LoadOfficeByIDCallback(void *vResult, int nNumberOfColumns, char **cData, char **cColumnNames) _NOEXCEPT;
    static int _LoadLandlordByIDCallback(void *vResult, int nNumberOfColumns, char **cData, char **cColumnNames) _NOEXCEPT;
    static int _FindBuildingsInAreaCallback(void *vSuitableBuildings, int nNumberOfColumns, char **cData, char **cColumnNames);

private:
    void _OpenConnection(); //exception
    void _CloseConnection() _NOEXCEPT;

    sqlite3 *m_sqlHandler;
    const char *m_cDBFile = "DB.sqlite";

    const std::string m_strQueryPrefix = "SELECT ";
    const std::string m_strQueryAny = "*";
    const std::string m_strQuerySource = " FROM ";
    const std::string m_strQueryConditions = " WHERE ";
    const std::string m_strQueryEqual = " = ";
    const std::string m_strQueryPt1 = "(XCoordinate BETWEEN";
    const std::string m_strQueryRange = " AND ";
    const std::string m_strQueryPt3 = ") AND (YCoordinate BETWEEN ";
    const std::string m_strQueryPt4 = ")";
};
```

And file CLocalDBManager.cpp contains these 2 includes and implementations of class functions

```
#include "CLocalDBManager.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
```

Also, these errors appear every time, no matter if I included CLocalDBManager.h in unit test .cpp or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out, that problem was with precompiled headers, disabled them and everything works fine